# changes to db from csharp are partly commited

Tags: c#, .net, oracle-sqldeveloper

so as title says, I have a .net program that has a method( names dont matter )..
so theres a method where I loop through a datatable and fill it with data from csv, then i build a query where I add the parameters and do

```
insert into bakashot id,name,bla values(:id,:name,:bla);
```

and I build the parameters like this for example

```
cmd.Parameters[":id"].Value = id;
```

Anyways, all good, database table is filled with values.

Now, I have another table lets say bakashot_history, I want before that insert statement to the bakashot table, to take the records from original bakashot, insert them to the bakashot_history table, and then clean the records from the bakashot table.

I've noticed that it will only commit if I put a debug on, otherwise theres no exception or anything -it just wont commit.

so Im thinking like, if the insert statement went well without any need of debug or thread.sleep(which I tried aswell) , why do the DELETE statement and the "Transfer"(insert into a from b) suddenly needs the debug? thats wierd and im clueless..

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Given that Oracle and C# aren't broken we can infer that the details do matter so if you can provide them it will be a lot easier than everybody else providing speculative guesses.

Comment: The functions themselves are too long..

Answer (score 0):

nobody replied to my post,but eitherway the solution was wrapping everything with oracle transaction

```
        using (OracleTransaction tran = myConnection.BeginTransaction())
{            
         StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO Bakashot_Mll_TOCharge 
          (ID)" + "VALUES (:ID");

        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql.ToString(), myConnection))
                {
                    cmd.Transaction = tran;
                    AddTableParameters(cmd);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters[":ID"].Value = row[0];                    
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }

                }
     -----//this is the part that didnt work unless the debug mode was on\\------
                using (OracleCommand com = new 
                          OracleCommand("Store_And_Delete", myConnection))
                {
                    com.Transaction = tran;
                    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                tran.Commit();
                myConnection.Close();
            }
```